# Based on a condition, how to make a dropdown list single select or multiselect?

Tags: php, html, phalcon

I had a requirement where in an employee list dropdown given,
if selectMultiple is set, the dropdown should allow multiple selects, and if selectMultiple is not set, it shouldn't.

```
<select name="employeeList[]" id="employeeList" class="form-
control" multiple="<?=$selectMultiple?>">
    <?php
    foreach($employeeList as $employee) {

        echo "<option value='" . $employee->$employeeId . "'>" . 
        $employee->employeeName . "</option>";

    }    
    ?>
</select>
```

It's a `phtml` file, and `$selectMultiple` is passed from a controller(as in Phalcon). I have tried something like passing, `$selectMultiple ="multiple"`, so the code will look like

```
<select name="employeeList[]" id="employeeList" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
```

and `$selectMultiple=""` for the single select case.

```
<select name="employeeList[]" id="employeeList" class="form-control" multiple="">
```

But the very presence of multiple attribute itself makes the dropdown list elligible for multiselect.

In short, in either cases, it triggers multiselect regardless of the condition. Please help.

Comment: You must remove multiple attribute from your select for single select case. Existence of "multiple" itself allows multiple selection even if don't use multiple="multiple".

Comment: you can try this `<?= isset($selectMultiple) ? $selectMultiple : '' ?>`

Comment: @Joppy Thanks, but still the presence of multiple attribute makes it possible for multiselect.

Comment: @Shabnam yes as what Rajan mentioned above the existence of "multiple" will allow multiselect. You should not set the $selectMutiple or set it to empty string if you don't want to allow multiselect.

Comment: @Joppy That makes sense. But I am confused since I need both the cases working - single select and multiselect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write your code like

> You need to pass `$selectMultiple = "multiple"` or `$selectMultiple = ''`

```
<select name="employeeList[]" id="employeeList" class="form-control" <? echo !empty($selectMultiple) ? $selectMultiple : '' ?>>
<?php
foreach($employeeList as $employee) {

    echo "<option value='" . $employee->$employeeId . "'>" . 
    $employee->employeeName . "</option>";

}    
?>
```

Comment: I was getting single select drop downs in both the cases with the above code.

Comment: My mistake you need to pass `$selectMultiple =''` instead of `$selectMultiple = 0`

Comment: Yes that works perfectly could you please update your answer so that I may accept that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried introducing a new variable "chooseId" to get rid of the multiple attribute and hence worked! 
Modified the select tag to,

```
<select name="employeeList[]" id="employeeList" class="form-control"
<?php if ($chooseId== 1) { ?> multiple="multiple" <?php } ?>>
<?php
  foreach($employeeList as $employee) {

    echo "<option value='" . $employee->$employeeId . "'>" . 
    $employee->employeeName . "</option>";

}    
?>
</select>
```

Now the code recognises the **multiple** attribute and enables multiselect only when chooseId is 1, otherwise single select works normally.